# `healthCheckPath` remains null after `az webapp config set`

Tags: azure-cli, azure-webapps

I'm attempting to automate enabling the Health Check function on several hundred webapps.
For context, I've already successfully utilized `az webapp update` on the same test app in the same az context.
Though there are 2 additional fields to be configured, all examples I've found denote the below line of code as sufficient to enable health checks and set the path.

`az webapp config set --resource-group "rg123" --name "123-WebApp-45678" --generic-configurations  '{"healthCheckPath": "/910/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F"}'`

I can clearly see `"healthCheckPath": null,` in the properties returned when I run the code, regardless of whether or not I've manually configured health checks in Azure Portal (which was done for testing purposes and later disabled).

When I run my original code:

`az webapp config set --resource-group "rg123" --name "123-WebApp-45678" --generic-configurations  '{"healthCheckPath": "/910/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F"}'`

There is no change to the value for `"healthCheckPath"`. In fact, this value does not seem to even reflect the actual state of the webapp.

I need a CLI solution (or PowerShell, if need be) to enable the Health Check feature and set the `"healthCheckPath"`

Is it my syntax? Am I operating on outdated info?
Again, my other CLI interactions have succeeded with no change in Azure context.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`az webapp config set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-set) will update the configuration settings of a web app as you already did.

I've used the same command structure as you and was able to enable the health check feature with a given path as shown below.

```bash
az webapp config set -g <resourcegroup> -n <webapp> --generic-configurations '{"healthCheckPath": "/910/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F"}'
```

[image]

[image]

I've visited the below resource web page, and it is also visible under the `site config property >> health check path`.

https://resources.azure.com/

[image]

*Note:* Upgrade the Az CLI version to the latest releases, also clear the cache with `az cache purge` command and try executing the same command.

Alternatively, you can use [`Set-AzWebApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp?view=azps-11.2.0) PowerShell command to update the site configuration of a web app.

Refer [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/14998) for the PowerShell approach.